# Can't see declared fields when doing reflection on a class rather than an object

Tags: java, reflection, static

So, I'm playing around with reflection in Java and noticed something that I find strange. I created a class that accepts an Object and then lists fields and methods that have the annotation "publish" (that I also made). When I feed it an instance of a class it works fine, but when I give it a class with static fields and methods (i.e. MyThing.class), I can't see anything. My original code had a bug, which meant that I actually used the hard coded class rather than the class I used in the constructor, like this:

```
Object obj = MyThing.class;
Field[] fields = obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields(); // correct version
Field[] fields = MyThing.class.getDeclaredFields(); // not as intended
```

In the latter case, I can see the fields, but in the first (correct version) I can't. Even more curious, if I do "toString" in both cases, I get the same result, but if I do "getName" they are different:

```
Object obj = MyThing.class;
System.out.println("toString="+obj.toString()); // --> class MyThing
System.out.println("getName="+obj.getClass().getName()); // --> java.lang.Class
```

I realize there is a difference between the two, but it is slightly annoying that "toString" somehow sees the original class, but when I try to get to the original class it seems to be gone. If I know which class Object really is, I could do a cast and make it work, but it kind of defeats the purpose of the thing...
I've tried to create a more complete example below and my question (finally) is: Is there a way I can get to the actual class of Object using something like "getClass"?

I have the following simple class declared:

```
public class MyThing {

    @Publish
    public double value1 = 1.0;
    @Publish
    public static double value2 = 2.0;
    public static int value3 = 3;
    
    public static void method1() {
        System.out.println("One");
    }

    @Publish
    public static double method2(double value) {
        return value*value;
    }

    @Publish
    public int method3(double value) {
        return (int) Math.floor(value);
    } 
}
```

Where "@Publish" is a simple annotation to make things easier to find:

```
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Retention;

@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface Publish {

}
```

If I then run the following:

```
    Object c1 = new MyThing();
    System.out.println("Object---------"+c1.toString());
    Field[] fields = c1.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    System.out.print("Fields:");
    for (Field f:fields) {
        if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Publish.class)) { 
            System.out.print(" "+f.getName());
        }
    }
    Method[] methods= c1.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    System.out.print("\nMethods:");
    for (Method m:methods) {
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Publish.class)) { 
            System.out.print(" "+m.getName());
        }
    }

    Object c2 = MyThing.class;
    System.out.println("\n\nClass---------"+c2.toString());
    Field[] fields2 = c2.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    System.out.print("Fields:");
    for (Field f:fields2) {
        if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Publish.class)) { 
            System.out.print(" "+f.getName());
        }
    }
    Method[] methods2= c2.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    System.out.print("\nMethods:");
    for (Method m:methods2) {
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Publish.class)) { 
            System.out.print(" "+m.getName());
        }
    }

    System.out.println("\n\nDirect Class---------"+MyThing.class.toString());
    Field[] fields3 = MyThing.class.getDeclaredFields();
    System.out.print("Fields:");
    for (Field f:fields3) {
        if (f.isAnnotationPresent(Publish.class)) { 
            System.out.print(" "+f.getName());
        }
    }
    Method[] methods3= MyThing.class.getDeclaredMethods();
    System.out.print("\nMethods:");
    for (Method m:methods3) {
        if (m.isAnnotationPresent(Publish.class)) { 
            System.out.print(" "+m.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

I get the following:

```
Object---------MyThing@6ff3c5b5
Fields: value1 value2
Methods: method2 method3

Class---------class MyThing
Fields:
Methods:

Direct Class---------class MyThing
Fields: value1 value2
Methods: method2 method3
```

In the second case, where I try to create an Object of MyThing.class, I can see the class name if I do "toString", but I don't get any of the fields or methods. If I use MyThing.class directly (as in the third case), I see the methods and fields - but I actually wasn't expecting to see the non-static methods and fields...

Comment: I am trying to do reflection on an unknown class. If I do it on an instance of the class it works fine, but if I try to do it on the class (in my case the class only has static fields and no methods so Java complain when I make an instance of it), it fails. I noted that "toString" seem to retain the class information and I assume they use reflection to find that info, but when I try to do reflection, it doesn't work. Maybe the Class<?>-thing will work... Nope. That did the opposite of what I want, but it works exactly as you said :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that `obj` stores an instance of `Class`, you should cast it, rather than calling `getClass`, to get a `Class`.

```
Field[] fields = ((Class<?>)obj).getDeclaredFields();
```

I'm not sure where `obj` comes from, but maybe it should have been declared to be a `Class<?>` in the first place.

Calling `getClass` on `obj` would get the `Class` instance representing the class `Class`, aka `Class.class`, obviously not what you want.

Perhaps this is another bug in your code, and that `obj` isn't actually meant to be an instance of `Class`, and instead meant to be an instance of `MyThing`? If that is the case, then calling `obj.getClass()` actually makes sense, and you should fix *that* bug instead.

As for why `toString` outputs the same results for both, it is because this isn't a fair comparison. You are comparing these two:

```
obj.toString()
MyThing.class.toString()
```

`obj` stores `MyThing.class`, so by dynamic dispatch at runtime, of course they are the same.

A fairer comparison would be:

```
obj.getClass().toString()
MyThing.class.toString()
```

Now you can see that the first outputs `class java.lang.Class`.

Edit:

You seem to think that you need to assign `obj = MyThing.class` (as opposed to an instance of `MyThing`),  in order to get the static fields of `MyThing`. This is incorrect. `getFields` will return both instance and static fields. You do not need to make `obj` be anything special to get its static fields.

You can check if a field is static by doing:

```
Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())
```

Just check if the above is true to filter the (non)-static fields out if you do not want them.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, perhaps my example was over-simplified... But to clarify - I made a class (called Reflector) that accepted an object and told you which parts of it was "published". When I sent it an object instance of a class (like MyThing) everything was fine, but I then tried it with a class with only static fields - which shouldn't be instantiated and thus I did MyOtherThing.class - it didn't. The Reflector still runs, but can't see the fields in the class.

Comment: @sventuba Ah I understand what your confusion is now. You should still pass the instance for the static fields if you are using `getClass`. If you have the `Class` instance itself, you can just cast and call `getFields` directly on it.

Comment: right! That's what I thought as well... But then I got stuck trying to figure out if I was looking at an instance of a class or the class itself... I tried variations of "instanceof" but that only works if I explicitly KNOW what the class is supposed to be. I guess I could write two versions of the code...

Comment: @sventuba See my latest edit. Perhaps, you are just looking for a way to check if a field/method is static?

Comment: @sventuba you don’t need to have two versions of the code. The version getting a `Class` (and not an object to call `getClass()` on), is the only correct one. In other words, `MyThing.class.getDeclaredFields()` will give you static and non-static fields anyway, so you never need to create a `MyThing` instance to find out which fields exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help and patience :). The background here is that I'm trying to wrap my old head around the concept of micro services and Docker. So I made a bunch of small services that talk via ZMQ. I added dynamic discovery of interfaces and started using reflection to figure out what I could do to each service which lead to creating my Reflector-class that lists things that you can do. It works fine, but I have to feed it an INSTANCE of a class for it to be happy and when I instantiate class with only static fields I get a warning. Which lead to my example code...